# spamassassin via procmail: .procmailrc moves spam messages, but /etc/procmailrc doesn't

Tags: spamassassin, procmail

I am trying [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin/tags/spamassassin_current_release_3.3.x/procmailrc.example) to set up spamassassin via procmail globally. It successfully adds the X-Spam headers, but it does not move messages to the spam mboxes.

However, using this example locally, at each user's .procmailrc file, does work (commenting out, as instructed, `DROPPRIVS=yes`).

I guess this is related to file permissions, but I'm lost about how to fix it. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Following tripleee's suggestion, I enabled logging with the following results:

```
# cat /var/log/proclog 
procmail: Assigning "DROPPRIVS=yes"
procmail: Assuming identity of the recipient, VERBOSE=off
procmail: Lock failure on "spamassassin.lock"
procmail: Lock failure on "almost-certainly-spam.lock"
procmail: Error while writing to "almost-certainly-spam"
procmail: Lock failure on "probably-spam.lock"
procmail: Error while writing to "probably-spam"
From root@example.net  Sun Feb 12 06:12:44 2012
  Folder: /var/mail/user
```

Comment: Please add VERBOSE=yes and post the log output of a sample run.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (I didn't know about VERBOSE=yes...). I have included the resulting log entry. I believe procmail is trying to create/update the files almost-certainly-spam and probably-spam in the directory /var/mail/user (which is actually the fresh-mails mbox), instead of in user's home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record I'm answering this, but the credit goes to tripleee for his suggestion. Adding the following line (or similar) in `/etc/procmailrc` fixes the issue:

```
MAILDIR=$HOME
```